# Adding node to (X)HTML from XML

Tags: xml, xhtml

I am dealing with a script in JavaScript that fetches XML from an external source and adds nodes from the XML file to the (X)HTML document.

I have the following piece of code. (Not tested, only a prototype)

```
var destination; // an <ul> in XHTML document
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item"); // XML nodes
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
    var item = document.createElement("li"); // XHTML document
    item.appendChild(nodes[i].cloneNode(true));
    destination.appendChild(item);
}
```

I want to know if this solution is viable because the nodes belong to different namespaces.

Thank you!

Comment: @Tomolak: XHTML. Edited the question!

Comment: You're appending to the XML here `nodes.appendChild(item)` not to the XHMTL and it's even a collection not a node, which does not have `appendChild` method

Comment: @KARASZI István: modified the code… Meant to append it to `destination`, a little bit unconscious now.

Comment: @Ryan: Have you seen `importNode()`? — [see MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode): *"Creates a copy of a node from an external document that can be inserted into the current document."*

Comment: @Tomalak: thank you, seems to be the stuff I am looking for. I think you could make it an answer? I will try it out. Sorry that I misspelled you name in the second comment…

Comment: It seems like you are adding elements from the external XML into the XHTML document. If these elements are not valid XHTML elements (along with the correct namespace) the resulting document will no longer be valid XHTML. As far as I know XHTML does not support mixing arbitrary namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `importNode()` is doing what you want.

It's a standard DOM Level 2 method, see [the spec on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#Core-Document-importNode) an [description on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode):

> **Summary**
>   Creates a copy of a node from an external document that can be inserted into the current document.

Even though it is a standard method, do a test for cross-browser support.

Comment: @Tomalak: I gave it a try and unfortunately it doesn't work… The imported `<a>` node doesn't show as a link.

Comment: @Tomalak: [this](http://i51.tinypic.com/2qd8umd.png) is it, the upper half the render result, the bottom half Firebug pane. It's just the same behaviour as directly appending an XML child to the XHTML document.

Comment: @RyanLi: Can you check which namespace the imported nodes are in? Looks like the `<a>` is not in the XHTML namespace and therefore it is not recognized.

Comment: @Tomalak: Firebug tells me that its `namespaceURI` is null…

Comment: @RyanLi: That's the reason why it does not work. The namespace must be there, but `importNode()` copies the original namespace. See http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crossbrowserscripting for a cross-browser safe alternative that might be useful. It re-creates the nodes instead of importing them and thus they will inherit the correct namespace.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks for the link. I thought the XML document at ALA also requires namespace declarations? It didn't but it worked. Anyway, I added namespace and it worked for me. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Tomalak: the acronym of "A List Apart". :-)

Comment: @Ryan: D'oh. Of course. :-) I have not tested their code, admittedly, so the namespace thing was a guess. Anyway I'm glad to hear that you got it working.